# Django 1.11 endpoint slow, nested serializer with too many results

Tags: python, django

I have the following models `model_A`, `model_B`, `model_c`.

- `model_B` has a foreign key on `model_A`
- `model_C` has a foreign key on `model_B`

With the below code I am able to get the `c__objects` from the endpoint `/a/<a_id>` as a nested property on the list results for the `a_id` given.

Example response

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "A record in model_A",
    "email": "example@email.com",
    "c__objects": [
        {
            "id": 54,
            .
            . more-stuff-here
            .
        }
    ],
    .
    .
    .
}
```

#### models.py

```
class model_A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-id"]

    def c__objects(self):
        return C.objects.filter(b__a=self).filter(end_date__gte=now())


class model_B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, related_name="a")
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-id']
    .
    .
    .


class model_C(models.Model):
    b = models.ForeignKey(B, related_name="b")
    description = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)

    class Meta:
       ordering = ['-id']
    .
    .
    .
```

#### views.py

```
class A_ViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        queryset = model_A.objects.all()
        obj = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
        serializer_context = {'request': request}
        serializer = A_Details_Serializer(obj, context=serializer_context)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

#### serializers.py

```
class A__Details_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # below line kills the performance, when there are too many c__objects 
    c__objects = YetAnotherSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = A
        fields = ('id',
                  'name',
                  'email',
                  'description',
                  'c__objects')
```

Now all of these are fine it works when the nested `c__objects` aren't much, however let's say the `c__objects` were 300-400 records this would take ages to return the response. I have read many things about `select_related()` and `prefetch_related()` however I am not really sure on how to optimise the above code using them. Any ideas?

---

Useful links / articles found while attempting to find a solution (but still no luck):

- https://hackernoon.com/all-you-need-to-know-about-prefetching-in-django-f9068ebe1e60
- https://medium.com/quant-five/speed-up-django-nested-foreign-key-serializers-w-prefetch-related-ae7981719d3f
- http://ses4j.github.io/2015/11/23/optimizing-slow-django-rest-framework-performance/

Comment: Sounds like you need an index on the SQL level.  This requires you to see the raw SQL and analyze it.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/optimization/

Comment: `prefetch_related` is the way to go. On the `model_A.objects.all()` queryset. And remove `c__objects` method entirely.

Comment: @spectras thank you I will try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `c__objects` in the `A` model is creating too many queries.

You can fetch all the `C` objects, you can use `select_related` to fetch the `B` fields, through which you can filter the current `A` objects.

Using [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield), you can serialize the filtered C objects using `YetAnotherSerializer`.

**Solution**:

```
class A_ViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        queryset = model_A.objects.all()
        obj = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)

        # add all C objects which has end_date greater than or equal to `now`
        serializer_context = {
            'request': request,
            'all_c_objects': C.objects.filter(end_date__gte=now()).select_related('b')
        }
        serializer = A_Details_Serializer(obj, context=serializer_context)
        return Response(serializer.data)

class A__Details_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    c__objects = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_c__objects(self, obj):
        all_c_objects = self.context.get('all_c_objects')
        if all_c_objects:
            c_objects = []
            for item in all_c_objects:
                if item.b.a == obj:
                    c_objects.append(item)
            return YetAnotherSerializer(c_objects, many=True).data

        return []

    class Meta:
        model = A
        fields = ('id',
                  'name',
                  'email',
                  'description',
                  'c__objects')
```

Comment: Sorry just got passed this error, it actually doesn't fill the array in the `get_c__objects` def now..

Comment: Is `c__objects` empty? It can be due to the `A` object isnt associated with any `C` object or there are no C objects greater than or equal to `now()`. Please check if these conditions are met.

Comment: I have printed the `serializer_context` and I can see the results. Something in the serializer definition `get_c__objects` empties them

Comment: you are saying that `all_c_objects` comes out to be `None` in `def c__objects`?